# Onclick imageview to new layout page ex tours.xml

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to figure out how I can make an intent onclick from an image I have in the RecycleView, now its just a show dialog that says "I have press the image". But I want it to go to another activity called Tours where I can see the name, image, and information about the image that was clicked.

But I really need help, I have tried all day now, and I am new to android.
This is my code in my main activity:

```
List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
lLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);

RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, rowListItem);
rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
```

I think it is this page i need to change so the link works.
This is my RecyclerViewHolders.java

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public TextView countryName;
    public ImageView countryPhoto;

    public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        countryName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        countryPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Country Position = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I have tried to change (public void onClick(View view) to intent and the code I find so I can go to another activity, but I get errors all the time in the RecyclerViewAdapter.java
I hope someone can help me to figure this out.

This is the RecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {

    private List<ItemObject> itemList;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<com.example.test.ItemObject> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public com.example.test.RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_list, null);
        com.example.test.RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new com.example.test.RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(com.example.test.RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
        holder.countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
        holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? If you have the context it should be easy to open a new activity.   Intent a = new Intent (context, Tours.class) context.startActivity(a)

Comment: I cant remember how i did, i tryed your code, StartActivity is all red and i get error : /R.java: AAPT: error: invalid symbol name 'xxxxxx:id/null'.

Comment: Can you past your RecyclerViewAdapter code as of now it seems you have a constructor in adapter which takes context of your activity use that activity to start new Activity and to be frank this error seems related to your resource file

Comment: i get this error: /app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/r/R.java: AAPT: error: invalid symbol name 'com.example.xxxx:id/null'.

Comment: It seems there is a problem with R.java file just do invalidate cache n restart

Comment: I find the error..
In the Tours file i had : android:layout_below="@+id/null", i just delete that and it works.

Comment: Cool congrats this was something silly which happens at times with developers :p